# extract few words before and after the specific word regex in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
r'((?:\S+\s+){0,3}\bwhite\b\s*(?:\S+\s+){0,3})
```

The result of above regex for below sentence is

```
sentence = This is a white floral garment.
result = This is a white floral
```

But I want the result as

```
wanted result = This is a white floral garment
```

I want 3 words before and after the white word. If there are not three word after white than at least get all which are present there.

Comment: The problem is that `\s+` requires at least 1 whitespace (at the end). You may try `(?:\S+\s+){0,3}white(?:\s+\S+){0,3}`

Comment: Maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199812/how-can-i-get-words-after-and-before-a-specific-token can be used to close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it by adding a word boundary `\b` to the subattern for words after `white` and making the space optional

```
((?:\S+\s+){0,3}\bwhite\b\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,3})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHiLCV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
((?:\S+\s+){3,}\bwhite\b\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){3,})
```

`(?:\S+\s+){3,}\bwhite\b` minimum 3 words before  the word 'white'

`s*(?:\S+\b\s*){3,}` after minimum 3 word

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHiLCV/4)**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could match one or more word characters `\w+` followed by a whitespace character `\s` and repeat that 3 times `{3}` to match 3 words before the word "white".

Then match "white" and after that match a whitespace character and one or more times a word character and repeat that 0 - 3 times `{0,3}` so if there are 3 or less words following you would match that.

[`(?:\w+\s){3}white(?:\s\w+){0,3}`](https://regex101.com/r/wTA9YL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I used the above, but had issues if a comma came after the target word.

Playing around with the regex, this seemed to work on sentences like:

I want a white floral garment, etc.

```
((?:\S+\s+){0,3}\bwhite\b\w*(?:\W+\b\w*){0,3})
```